# Common Q&A for sources of learning materials

Tags: discussion

Lately there have been a few questions requesting sources of learning materials.

- [What Math is used in Development Economics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-math-is-used-in-development-economics)
- https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9676/what-are-some-good-resources-online-courses-to-learn-economics-from-scratch
- [Getting up to Date on Macro](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9677/getting-up-to-date-on-macro)

There were other many similar questions in the not-so-distant past.

To the extent that we as a site want to remain helpful for new economic students, and that these students would typically ask reference request questions of the above sort, I was wondering if it would useful to have a community wiki question on commonly used source of textbooks/videos/learning materials for intro/intermediate/advanced micro/macro/econometrics/math econ/labor/development/etc.

Once asked and answered, this question should be protected by moderators, so that it stays relatively stable. In the future when people ask "what's a good source for learning ...", we can then close them as duplicates of this "big-list" question. I think this is more encouraging and helpful for new learners than to close their questions as "too broad" or "off topic".

Answer (score 3):

Such lists are a bad fit for Q&A.

"Community wiki" isn't a valid excuse for off-topic questions, such as big-list and shopping/recommendation questions.

If one's inclination is "this question should be community wiki", that's a good sign that it probably shouldn't be on the site at all. See [the related StackOverflow blogpost on this.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)

If a big list of resources belongs anywhere on Stack Exchange, it's typically in one or more tag wikis. For example, the [SO android tag-wiki has a big list of related resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info)

Comment: What I meant for the big-list question to achieve is to make it easier to close questions on learning resources without discouraging new learners (probably also new Econ.SE users) from seeking help on this platform again. Obviously I didn't realize one can edit so much information into a tag wiki. Now that I know this is possible, I agree that tag wikis are a better place to hold such information than a community wiki.

Comment: I agree with @EnergyNumber's answer. On a note of actual policy though I will keep voting 'Leave open' on learning material requests until the tag wikis actually contain suggestions about learning materials, which currently they do not.